# Group By results as individual column names

Tags: mysql

How to get the groupby result as column names

if staff table is there when we use

> select count(*) from staff group by gender; gives me as

[image]

but i need them as columns Male  | Female | None

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level (e.g. with a bit of PHP)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select sum(case when gender = 'Male' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Male',
sum(case when gender = 'Female' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Female',
sum(case when gender not in ('Male','Female') or gender is null then 1 else 0 end) as 'None'
from staff;
```